# What parameters are passed to CPQ Custom Visualforce Template Content?

Tags: visualforce, cpq

There is no official documentation on what parameters get passed to a [Custom Template Content section](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.cpq_template_content.htm&type=5). What parameters are available to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some debugging, the following parameters were identified:

| Parameter | Description |
| --- | --- |
| inline | Unsure of how this is used. It appears to be boolean and is `1` in testing. |
| language | The language to render the document in. For example `en_US`. |
| preview | `1` indicates the preview option was selected, `0` indicates the document should be generated. |
| qid | The Quote Id. |
| tid | The Template Id. |

These can be used directly in your Visualforcepage using syntax such as `language="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.language}"` or in your Apex controller such as `Id templateId = (Id) ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('tid');`